# Angular2+ display data from storage onto dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, ionic-framework

I have an array of data. What I want from the view is to have an input box on the number of objects in the array and when the page is refreshed, whatever was saved into the input boxes, then that value gets display as the value in the input field.

```
data - [{value: 'value1', timeTitle: ''}, {value: 'value2', timeTitle: ''}]
```

HTML

```html
<div>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime min={{minDate}} displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate" formControlName="dateTime">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-list *ngFor="let detail of details; let i=index" formArrayName="times">
    <ion-item [formGroupName]="i">
      <ion-label>{{detail.timeTitle}}</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="h:mm A" formControlName="time"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>{{detail.purpose}}</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>

<button ion-button full (click)="next()" [disabled]="!timeForm.valid">Next</button>
```

TS

```js
ngOnInit() {

  this.timeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    dateTime: [''],
    times: this.formBuilder.array([this.createTime()])
  })

  this.addTimes()

  this.storage.get('saveTimes').then(res => {
    //DO STUFF HERE 
  })

}

createTime(): FormGroup{
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    time: ['', Validators.required]
  })
}

addTimes() {
  const time = this.createTime()
  this.times.push(time)
}

get times(): FormArray {
  return this.timeForm.get('times') as FormArray
}

next() {
  this.times = {
    requestedTime1: this.timeForm.value.times[1],
    requestedTime2: this.timeForm.value.times[0]
  }

  this.storage.set('saveTimes', this.times)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be pretty simple solution.

1. Any change in input box, trigger the `save` function.
2. `Save` function will basically convert the `array` to string by `JSON.stingify()` and save into `Cookie` or `Session Storge`.
3. Whenever user refresh the page. Component will re-intialize and will call to `ngOnInit` function.
4. In `ngOnInit` function, read the content from `Cookie`.
5. Convert Cookie `string` back to `array` by using `JSON.parse()`
6. Finally you can assign these array to original array in your class.

Comment: The issue is displaying that data in the view. It is not populating in the text field.